Can an employer use your FMLA “tardiness” from a previous time working for them in a re-hire situation?
I had a Family and Medical Leave Act (FMLA) with a job in the past but left on good terms. I left that job for another job a year or two ago. I applied this year to be rehired for an open position but was told my “tardiness” when I used my FMLA is a problem and they won’t even interview me. I wasn’t sure if that was covered by law and not allowed or not. Based out of PA

What does "tardiness" mean? If you're on leave - how are you tardy?

"tardiness" means coming in late. Did you mean "absenteeism"? While they shouldn't penalize you for being absent when you're officially on leave, at least it makes logical sense.

it could be announcung the FML very close to the requested leave.

This might be a question to take to an attorney familiar with labor law, but I'm not sure what you'd hope to gain. If an employer is being a pain in the neck during the hiring process, they're probably going to be a pain in the neck when you work for them.

The main right conferred by the Family and Medical Leave Act is the right to return to your job after the leave period. However, you're not trying to return to the job after your leave, you're trying to be rehired after quitting from that employer. I don't think there's anything in the FMLA that covers hiring.
When hiring someone, the laws enforced by the Equal Employment Opportunity Commission (EEOC) are relevant. These are primarily discrimination based on race, color, religion, sex (including gender identity, sexual orientation, and pregnancy), national origin, age (40 or older), disability or genetic information. It doesn't seem that people who have taken advantage of FMLA during a previous employment period are considered a protected class.
It doesn't seem fair that you can be discriminated against for taking advantage of a legal right, but that doesn't make it illegal.

Seems like discriminating against someone for using pregnancy leave is de facto discriminating against them for pregnancy to me.

"tardiness" is a weird word in this context. I don't think FMLA gives you the right to show up to work, but late.

@fectin I mentioned that in a comment above. It seems like either they misspoke or the OP misremembers. Presumably they're talking about absenteeism, not tardiness.
